# What is the necessity of CSS property background-repeat: repeat;

Tags: html, css

I think if background-repeat in CSS is not mentioned then by default browsers make it `background-repeat: repeat`.

So, what is the necessity of having a separate `background-repeat: repeat` property?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp read here :)

Comment: @Era — Why? W3Schools is *awful* and that page doesn't answer the question anyway.

Comment: @Quentin, no relate to OP question. Why do you say W3Schools is *awful*?

Comment: @Era the page doesn't answer the question. In fact I am reding from that page only

Comment: @Duannx — It's wrong more often than is reasonable. It misleading or not-quite-right a *lot*. It has tutorials which teach you to write code with gaping big security holes in it.

Comment: @Quentin, You are right. But, to be fair, it is not *awful*. I think it is a good place for beginer to learn

Comment: @Duannx — No. It is terrible place for a beginner to learn. They'll believe all the things it is wrong about. MDN is a better place for people to learn. The W3C tutorial wiki stuff if a better place for people to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value didn't exist in the first place, then it couldn't be the default value.

You also need a way to set it *back* to repeat if something else has changed it.